# Can you give me the answer within a period of time?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Today I got a notification from a user that asked if I wanted to deliver a solution on his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35359694/1449624) **today** or **tomorrow** by the end of the day. The reason I commented on the question because the original problem wasn't clear and I wanted more clarification and now he expects me to deliver an answer soon. I told him I can't deliver anytime soon, hoping that he won't draw hope on me.

I know that I'm not obligated to answer this but I want to be polite to this new user and I also want to let him know that this is not the way to ask for solutions from me (and on SO?). How can I express this in the politest way possible :)?

Comment: _"404 - This is a automated message, the user you tried to contact is no longer available."_

Comment: As you can see, I gave it a try. I think the message clearly explains without being insulting.... now let's see how OP reacts. ...

Comment: If I spot such terms and conditions in a newly posted question, I remove them straight away and without comment or explanation. Most of us do; there are at the time of writing only 35 questions [begging us to plz respond asap](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+plz+help+as+soon+as+possible). (It could be coincidence that most of them are downvoted.)

Comment: I usually point them to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6506/248731

Comment: @Jongware I feel this one is different because he didn't write it in his question but asked it in a comment after he knew his question got attention.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know if someone gets the hint if you link that post. It's a good answer nonetheless.

Comment: I believe the point of the question is to tell the user things in a gentle way. Just linking to a meta post, while technically correct, might not be enough to teach a new user how our site works.

Comment: Tell him/her to f.. find a contractor.

Comment: Tell the user that for your usual consulting of fee of $1000/hr you'll be happy to provide an answer on any schedule requested.

Comment: Rounded up to nearest 4 hours, first day up front.

Comment: I don't care whether they are new users or no.  It is selfish and insulting to ask SO contributors to provide estimates for free.  It's not the behavior of a software newb, it's the behaviour of someone who knows that arrogant and socially/professionally unacceptable behaviour is tolerated on SO, as long as it's from question posters.  Naturally, SO contributors wih anything remotely like a similar attitude will get suspended immediate.

Comment: In case of ASAP requests I usually use this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32140476/need-to-store-a-2d-list-but-not-using-array#comment52170418_32140476 (I know it is not completely related to this situation, but it is still worth spreading).

Comment: If anyone asks me for an estimate to answer I usually either ignore it or don't answe at all on purpose. Its insulting to imply that you get to set a deadline when im the one giving you free advice

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Stealing a bit from @Patrice in the comments, I suggest a more verbose approach. Softening his suggestion with showing a little understanding and, hopefully, comfort.

> I understand that you're on a deadline, but I can't afford to help you meet it in time. Please understand that Stack Overflow is a community of volunteers; we have our own projects and deadlines. Asking to get help before a certain time is not how this site works. It's supposed to be a repository of programming knowledge for the long term, where answers help both the asker and future visitors. I'm sorry I'm not able to help you further, but for now, I can only wish you good luck.

Comment: OK, is there a shortcut that inserts that because, unless the required action is shorter than typing a four-letter reply, I won't be doing it.  I would downvote, closevote and otherwise ignore.   The idea of actually spending the time to type in 90 words in reply to such a question is abhorrent.

Comment: @MartinJames You'd have to create a GreaseMonkey script, or other tool. Either that, or copy-paste the thing.

Comment: @MartinJames: [AutoReviewComments](//stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) will do that once you add the comment to its list.

Comment: I wish SO had canned responses - could be a perk based on rep - that would be awesome :)

Comment: CodeCaster's now-deleted comment prompted a flag containing a question that I'd frankly have loved to see in a full-blown meta discussion.

Comment: I think this is a bit _too_ polite, honestly.  The message is that Stack Overflow is an impersonal place (not just for _you_), but the message is phrased in the personal terms of _you_ and _I'm sorry_.  (I suppose it's better than being rude, though.)

Comment: I agree with @JeffreyBosboom. It's too polite and looks like a politician's answer to a voter's letter.

Comment: What if the answer is being overly polite on purpose, either as a way of being sarcastic or in an attempt to scare the user off? ;)

Comment: LoL @BoltClock! No, it's not overly polite on purpose. Keep in mind that the request to answer in time was made in comments, _after_ there had already been interaction. Also keep in mind that the person who asks the question on SO may be under a lot of stress / pressure. That said, I'd be interested to see answers that are polite, not overly polite, and still drive the point home.

Comment: @BoltClock what was the question in the flag?

Comment: @CodeCaster: It was about imposing Western culture on an international site.

Comment: @BoltClock that would be an interesting discussion, but not one I'd like to be the instigator of.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Understandable. I'm considering starting a thread myself sometime. It's something I've thought about before.

Comment: @BoltClock that sounds like a interesting discussion to have.

Answer (score 4):

He was evidently waiting desperately for an attention to his question. When he got one, he started laying his time constraint on you. Few people really think that stackoverflow will give them quicker and easy solution. Of course it does. But those have to understand that those who answer are indeed trying to create a repository of good answers here rather than sitting idle and waiting on someone else to do their job.

Answer (score 3):

I think, in case of asking, or even polite application, it's ok. You can just answer yes or no.

You started commenting, so he understands that you can help him. Every other reader of the question thinks the same. So discussion in comments can be treated as as your readyness to help and other people can start skipping this question as there is already someone who wants to answer.

Explicit question about timing and explicit answer "no" resets skipping of the question by other users, so it is useful and has nothing bad.

You don't need special politeness or long descriptions, it's just a piece of information, helping other people to deside if they care to unswer the question or they should wait for your answer first.

> I could just easily answer yes or no but that doesn't stop him from doing it again. I don't think people skip questions when I just ask for clarification, or am I wrong?

It depends.

If I treat some comments as preparation for the answer and I understand that answering or understanding of the question requires some amount of time, it's very possible that I wouldn't be doing it at least for some period of time. Maybe I'll add question to favourites to see the answer latter, or just leave the browser tab open, or even close it. But if I don't see something especially interesting in this question, I won't start answering it immediately even if I would've start in case of no comments.

So clarifiing comments are reducing likelihood of other users response and explicit question about time with answer "no" just resets this effect.

Comment: I could just easily answer yes or no but that doesn't stop him from doing it again. I don't think people skip questions when I just ask for clarification, or am I wrong?

Comment: @A1rPun, updated the answer.

Comment: I think you meant "treat" and not "threat"...they're  not really the same. :)

Comment: @Paulie_D, yep :) Thank you.

Comment: No one "should understand we can help them" simply because we posted a comment.  Posting a comment asking for clarification simply means we didn't understand the question.  It's entirely possible that once we understand the question we still won't be able to answer it, and even if we can, asking for a time line is inappropriate.

Comment: @EthanFurman, maybe it should be so, but in fact it's not. I do not mean that any comment can be treated as redyness to answer, but some discussions can. Why do you think polite asking about time is inappropriate? It's not "Help me now! I need it to be done in 10 minites!!!", it's just a question "Would you help me, please? Or you'd like to leve it for someone else?" And everyone reading it would know what are you going to do. Why is it bad?

Comment: It's bad because it creates a force field directed towards the down and close vote icons.  Why should it be the task of an SO contributor to provide estimates at no cost?  Sorry, such posters are selfish and inconsiderate .....  people.

Comment: If a poster wants a quote for an answer before a specified deadline, s/he should be prepared to pay for it.

Comment: @EthanFurman: Being _able_ to answer the question is irrelevant. Choosing to is all that matters, and every single one of us reserves the right, without prejudice, not to do so. There is little worse than being accused of "not knowing the answer" to a crappy, poorly-asked question just because we have opted to be responsible and not even begin to answer it.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Your answer is well-written and I can tell that your intention is good, but you seem to have a misunderstanding about what Stack Exchange is. It's not a helpdesk. _Any_ discussion along the lines of "when can you have this done for me?" is completely inappropriate, by definition.

Comment: @PreferenceBean, it's the goal of network, but it's not the goal of people here. I'm talking not about those who ask but also about those who answers. Why are they interested in answering? Do they want to simply add a piece of information? Or they want something other? Seems like they have [other reasons (ru)](//meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/305/178988). Sorry, I don't know if there is such question in English somewhere here. Most answers are about communication, learning and studiing, helping and so on. People are not interested in "I'll post this and it'll be one piece of information more".

Comment: @PreferenceBean: I have no idea what you are trying to say in your response to my comment.

Comment: @EthanFurman: Which part of it did you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Politely tell them to go away. The purpose of this site is *not* to answer a particular person's question. It is to create a repository of good questions with good answers. That means questions that are useful to someone other than the original asker, perhaps *years* later. So their urgency should be irrelevant.  And punish them too, for their arrogant sense of entitlement.  Not just do they want experts to do work for them for free,  they have the nerve to tell people to get cracking and answer quickly. Punish them with a downvote for failing to research what this site is for.

Comment: Comments have nothing with quality of question. Why good question with comment about urgency should be treated as bad? Yes, author urgency is irrelevant to others, but it's not a problem for the site content.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using phrases like "go away" or "punish them... for their arrogant sense of entitlement". This is also not the purpose of the site. Unless a user is constantly making these types of requests a polite comment explaining to them the way [so] operates should be enough. If the user is abusing the site, flag one of their posts for moderation attention and explain the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you already answered your question:

"that this is not the way to ask for solutions from me (and on SO?)"

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow is an exchange place. Giving and taking. It is neither an answering machine nor a place for getting full comprehensive solutions for free.

If someone needs quick and comprehensive solutions, then s/he can always also pay a consultant.

Comment: Its not only that, SO is also a place where you need to be a true software engineer - one that takes time to research. You generally don't need to ask if you spend the proper amount of time and patience searching; in the years I've been using the site I've found every answer to every gnarly problem I had, right here on the site. Sometimes it just took an hour or two.

Answer (score -3):

A good answer which fits many situations:

*"Do you want it quick, or do you want it good ?"*